# Update and configure babel with React SSR

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

Ok, so I'm trying to update a pretty old auth code base with React(v15.2), React Router(v.2.3) with SSR and Webpack(v1.12). I got the codebase from [here](https://github.com/sahat/megaboilerplate) quite a while ago.

I pretty much have most of it done. I've updated React to 16x, RR to 3.2 and Wepback to 3.5. However I have some code in server.js in my backend that I can't quite seem to rectify. I think because the backend is pulling some React code in ES6 syntax that the backend (Node) can't understand because I don't have Webpack setup properly for the updated version.

So I have this code in my server.js for the backend. It relates to React and React Router for SSR.

```
// React and Server-Side Rendering
const routes = require('./src/routes');
const configureStore = require('./src/store/configureStore').default;

const app = express();



... for brevity




// React server rendering
app.use((req, res) => {
  let initialState = {
    auth: { token: req.cookies.token, user: req.user },
    messages: {}
  };

  const store = configureStore(initialState);

  Router.match({ routes: routes.default(store), location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message);
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    } else if (renderProps) {
      var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(Provider, { store: store },
        React.createElement(Router.RouterContext, renderProps)
      ));
      res.render('layouts/main', {
        html: html,
        initialState: store.getState()
      });
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(404);
    }
  });
});
```

That code is causing this error when I run nodemon server

```
/home/david/tutorials/react/mgbp/mgbp-default-refactored/src/routes.js:9
import React from 'react';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

`/src/routes.js` is my React routes file and its using import statements instead of the commonjs `require('')` statements on the backend.

However, when I run the command for webpack to build the client and server they compile correctly and without errors.

How can I solve this? How can I setup Babel to where the SSR code will work?

Comment: 1) why is register commented out, 2) to convert `import` and `export` to commonjs you need the write babel plugin or preset like `env` or  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs.html  also you can't have your source code and the register in the same file, you have to require the source code that is meant be compiled like this: https://github.com/overture-stack/arranger/blob/master/modules/server/index.js

Comment: instead of using regular node you can use babel-node so it can handle es6 syntax